# Substring of a string from the end of the string

Tags: c#, substring

I need to get the words from the end of a string. For example:

```
string1 = "Hello : World";
string2 = "Hello : dear";
string3 = "We will meet : Animesh";
```

I want output for

```
string1 = "World"
string2 = "dear"
string3 = "Animesh"
```

I want the word after the `:`.

Comment: Did you check `string.Split` ?

Answer (score 11):

Various ways:

```
var str = "Hello : World";
var result = str.Split(':')[1];
var result2 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(":") + 1);
```

[Clicky clicky - Live sample](http://ideone.com/gM0HU0)

EDIT:

In response to your comment. Index 1 won't be available for a string that does not contain a colon character. You'll have to check first:

```
var str = "Hello World";
var parts = str.Split(':');
var result = "";
if (parts.Length > 1)
    result = parts[1];
else
    result = parts[0];
```

[Clicky clicky - Another live sample](http://ideone.com/hkEOmq)

Comment: :: When I use it normally it works fine. But when I use in datagridview it shows an error. "Index was outside the bounds of the array." on 2nd line

Comment: That is because the string you're passing to it doesn't contain a colon character. To fix that, you'll have to check the length.. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string s = "We will meet : Animesh";
string[] x = s.Split(':');
string out = x[x.Length-1];
System.Console.Write(out);
```

Update in response to OPs' comment.

```
if (s.Contains(":"))
{
  string[] x = s.Split(':');
  string out = x[x.Length-1];
  System.Console.Write(out);
}
else
  System.Console.Write(": not found");
```

Comment: When I use it normally it works fine. But when I use in datagridview it shows an error. "DataGridViewComboBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }".

Comment: Does all your string have the colon (`:`) character? If the string does not have it, then there will be an error. Let me update the answer. Also what will happen if you do not have the `:` in your string?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string string1 = "Hello : World";
string string2 = "Hello : dear";
string string3 = "We will meet : Animesh";

string1 = string1.Substring(string1.LastIndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();
string2 = string2.Substring(string2.LastIndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();
string3 = string3.Substring(string3.LastIndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions is a good way to parse any texts and extract out what is needed:

```
Console.WriteLine (
   Regex.Match("Hello : World", @"[^\s]+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[0].Value);
```

This method will work, *unlike the other responses*, **even when there is no `:`**.